# input box disappearing if there is an error

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I have the following jQuery code that shows an input box if yes is selected.  My issue is that when I have an error the dropdown box's state is remembered yes/no but if yes is selected it does not show the input box why?

**jQuery:**

```
$("#add_fields_placeholder").change(function()
        {
            if($(this).val() == "yes")
        {
            $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').show();
            $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").show();
        }
        else
        {

            $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').hide();
            $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").hide();
        }
            });
```

**View:**

```
<label for="add_fields_placeholder">Placeholder: </label>
<select name="add_fields_placeholder" id="add_fields_placeholder">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="yes" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','yes', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "yes" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="no" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','no', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "no" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>>No</option>
</select>

<label for="add_fields_placeholderValue">Placeholder Text: </label>
<input type="text" name="add_fields_placeholderValue" id="add_fields_placeholderValue" value="<?php echo set_value('add_fields_placeholderValue'); ?>">
```

Comment: because in case of error dropdown change event will not fire

Comment: Why? Because the jQuery code is only executed when you change the value (e.g. when you click "yes" or "no"), not when the page (re)loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of an error the change event will not fire. Try to handle both onchange and page load events to get it right.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more maybe with an example.  Could I set it off via my PHP controller?